# IntelliJ IDEA 2017 JavaScript indention broken

Tags: intellij-idea

With the last update to v2017 I got this strange indention for function arguments:

```
const MyFunction = ({
                      b,
                      c, 
                      d,
                     }) => (
```

is there any way to get it back to just 2 spaces and not aligning it to the parenthesis?

```
const MyFunction = ({
  b,
  c, 
  d,
}) => (
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue; Destructuring parameters will be formatted as described in [WEB-25899](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25899) in a bug-fix update to 2017.1 (coming soon)